# How to bind a BLOB Variable to PL/SQL Block in Toad

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, blob

I would like to load a picture in to a oracle database (11g) through a stored procedure.

the script looks something like this:

```
declare 
  v_content BLOB;
begin
  v_content := :bind_variable;
  some_procedure(v_content);
end;
```

I tried to use Toad and SQL Developer there I have no choice of selecting BLOB types. 
Any ideas? I am also open for workarounds load a content from a file, on my local machine not on the database server.

Comment: I can confirm `Toad` do have the option of defining `type(BLOB)` of the bind variable.

Comment: @Ravi. I don't understand your comment. Could you explain please?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you would want to do something like this?

```
CREATE TABLE lob_table (id NUMBER, doc BLOB);
INSERT INTO lob_table VALUES (1, EMPTY_BLOB()); 

DECLARE
  src_lob  BFILE := BFILENAME('MY_DIR', '/tmp/me.gif');
  dest_lob BLOB;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO lob_table VALUES(2, EMPTY_BLOB())
     RETURNING doc INTO dest_lob;

  DBMS_LOB.OPEN(src_lob, DBMS_LOB.LOB_READONLY);
  DBMS_LOB.LoadFromFile( DEST_LOB => dest_lob,
                         SRC_LOB  => src_lob,
                         AMOUNT   => DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(src_lob) );
  DBMS_LOB.CLOSE(src_lob);

  COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Check out - https://community.oracle.com/thread/2400953?tstart=0
or see the oracle docs for other possibilities